# Grouping pages in Mezzanine

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, mezzanine

I'm new to Mezzanine, but I've got a project up and running and can generate customized `Page`s using my own model. I'd now like to group these pages into sections (and maybe subsections) like this:

```
Section1
    Subsection1
        Page1.1.1
        Page1.1.2
    Subsection2
        Page1.2.1
    ...
Section2
    Subsection1
        Page2.1.1
        Page2.1.2
    ...
```

and so on. How can I attach my `Page` objects to specific Section and Subsection categories (with an index page for each?) Do I need to create another Model to represent these categories and then a `page_processor` to generate the index or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Mezzanine, your categories of `Section1`, `Subsection1`, etc. need to be pages as well.

Say you wanted the following structure:

```
Movies
    Comedies
        Monty Python and the Holy Grail
```

You would first create a Mezannine `Page` (or `RichTextPage` or similar) with title "Movies", and enter some content (even if minimal), such as "These are the movies I watch too much".  This page will automatically contain links to any subpages once you create them.

To create a subpage like "Comedies", you would go to "Pages" under "Content" in the admin, and click on the "Add" dropdown menu in the "Movies" row you just created (and not the "Add" dropdown at the top-right of the page).

Follow the same pattern to create a subpage under "Comedies", and on that page ("Monty Python...") you'll likely enter the bulk of the content you actually want.

If it suits your needs, you can consider the other hierarchical pages to be nothing more than placeholder pages in a way, but those pages are usually a place to put content related to what the category itself is about.

The overall page structure will be mirrored in things like navigation menu dropdown trees.

**Changing the structure of existing pages:**

The Mezzanine Admin > Content > Pages page supports drag & drop for this.

Click a page's row near the right side (where the small up/down arrows are), and drag it to where you want it to go.  A dotted outline will appear indicating where the dropped page will go, as you move the mouse around.

If you want to move your existing page to be a subpage of another, you can position the dotted outline below the intended parent page, and then move the mouse right or left before dropping the page.  You will see the dotted outline's position change from indented to de-dented.  Dropping while the outline is indented will create a subpage.

Note that the right/left mouse adjustment to get the indent/dedent might be somewhat finicky, depending on the mouse's position.

Comment: Thanks, Christian. I think I understand a bit better... but when I create Pages under the subpage (e.g.  Comedies), I don't see an index of them and the content for my Comedies page is mandatory. Also, do you know how I can move my existing Pages to reside within the Comedies subpage?

Comment: I updated my answer to describe adjusting existing pages.  I also removed "optionally" from where I described entering content, since that was confusing.  I didn't intend to mean the field wasn't required (the page has to contain *something*).  As for not seeing an index... if you mean the hierarchical links/menus to navigate between your pages, then maybe check that you've set up your menus correctly.  Documentation here: http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/content-architecture.html#page-menus

Comment: That's really helpful, thanks. What I'd hoped for is an index in the content of the "Comedies" page rather than (or in addition to) the navigation menus. Can this be done without creating a new model?

Comment: Provided that you have selected "Left-hand tree" under "Show in menus" (in the page's admin), then Mezzanine will include those links within a sidebar (or elsewhere, as you prefer).  You need to have followed the page-menus documentation I linked to in my last comment.  If you've done that (ensuring the template code exists) and still are not seeing sidebar links, then it's likely a coding error. So I'd recommend a new question about that specifically, including your code and troubleshooting you've done.  I think that would be outside the scope of this question, which seems answered, yes?